# Visual Studio 2017 is stopped when do the restart application of nopcommerce 4.2

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nopcommerce, application-restart

When I do the restart application of nopCommerce 4.2 from admin side it always stop visual studio and as well as application.

So, from that plugin install and uninstall features is also not working.

There is any solution for that than let me know.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Actually install and uninstall features work properly.

Before stopping nopCommerce, the system name of the plugin is written into the plugins.json file.

Next time you start the application, it will get the plugin names from the PluginNamesToInstall section and install them.

---

plugins.json:

```
{
  "InstalledPluginNames": [],
  "PluginNamesToUninstall": [],
  "PluginNamesToDelete": [],
  "PluginNamesToInstall": [
         "systemName"
    ]
}
```

Comment: but their function is not working without restart application. And when I restart the application at that time vs2017 is stopped and application too.